# Why methods mouseExited and mouseEntered run together when I enter or exit JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jdialog

Yes, this question is already posted on JavaRanch but I do not understand them well.

I have JDialog which has MouseListener added as follows:

```
super.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof ConnectionTreeTooltip) {
                    System.out.println("mouse exited!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=" + e);
                    // hideTooltip();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof ConnectionTreeTooltip) {
                    System.out.println("mouse entered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=" + e);
                    // hideTooltip();
                }
            }
        });
```

`ConnectionTreeTooltip` is this jdialog.
The problem is that both these two methods are invoked whenever mouse enters or exits JDialog. They merely run together.

The code of my JDialog:

```
public class ConnectionTreeTooltip extends JDialog {
...........
public ConnectionTreeTooltip(ConnectionsTree connectionsTree) {
        super(connectionsTree.getMainFrame(), "", false);
        super.setUndecorated(true);
        super.setFocusableWindowState(false);
.............
super.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        super.pack();
    }
```

`connectionsTree.getMainFrame()` returns instance of JFrame.

**EDIT** Here is full code :

```
public ConnectionTreeTooltip(ConnectionsTree connectionsTree) {
        super(connectionsTree.getMainFrame(), "", false);
        super.setUndecorated(true);
        super.setFocusableWindowState(false);

        this.connectionsTree = connectionsTree;
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) super.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.blue, Color.red));
        tipLabel = new JLabel();
        // by default, JLabel is not focusable.
        tipLabel.setFocusable(true);
        tipLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tipLabel) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return preferredSizeOfScrollPane;
            }
        };
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 1, 1));
        super.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof ConnectionTreeTooltip) {
                    System.out.println("mouse exited!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=" + e);
                    // hideTooltip();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof ConnectionTreeTooltip) {
                    System.out.println("mouse entered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=" + e);
                    // hideTooltip();
                }
            }
        });
        tipLabel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // tipLabel can key events only if it is visible and focused
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 32) {
                    unFocusTipLabel();
                }
            }
        });
        super.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        super.pack();
    }
```

Why is that and what is wrong with my JDialog or my MouseListener?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that you'll want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) for us to better understand your problem and possibly offer a solution.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood your JDialog holds a component inside of it that steals the mouse listener from the dialog itself, and so when your mouse enters the dialog, the dialog senses the mouse entering, but then the mouse immediately enters the dialog's component (the JScrollPane perhaps), the mouselistener senses that you've left the dialog and have entered its child component.

For example, my SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseListenerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("My Frame");
      mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      mainFrame.add(new JPanel() {
         {
            add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog") {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  ConnectionTreeTooltip cttt = new ConnectionTreeTooltip(
                        mainFrame);
                  cttt.setVisible(true);
               }
            }));
         }
      });
      mainFrame.pack();
      mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);

   }
}

class ConnectionTreeTooltip extends JDialog {

   public ConnectionTreeTooltip(JFrame mainFrame) {
      super(mainFrame, "", false);
      setUndecorated(true);
      setFocusableWindowState(false);
      add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20, 40)));
      ((JPanel)getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
      pack();
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof ConnectionTreeTooltip) {
               System.out.println("mouse exited!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=" + e);
               // hideTooltip();
            }
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof ConnectionTreeTooltip) {
               System.out.println("mouse entered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=" + e);
               // hideTooltip();
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

now the tough part is to figure out how to use the GlassPane to get your Mouse enter/leaving information, but still allow the mouse events to be passed onto the dialog that's below the glass pane.

---

**Edit**

Yep the solution is to use the glass pane:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseListenerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("My Frame");
      mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      mainFrame.add(new JPanel() {
         {
            add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog") {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  ConnectionTreeTooltip cttt = new ConnectionTreeTooltip(
                        mainFrame);
                  cttt.setVisible(true);
               }
            }));
         }
      });
      mainFrame.pack();
      mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);

   }
}

class ConnectionTreeTooltip extends JDialog {

   public ConnectionTreeTooltip(JFrame mainFrame) {
      super(mainFrame, "", false);
      setUndecorated(true);
      setFocusableWindowState(false);
      add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20, 40)));
      ((JPanel) getContentPane()).setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
      pack();

      JComponent glassPane = (JComponent) getGlassPane();
      glassPane.setVisible(true);

      glassPane.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

      @Override
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
         System.out.println("mouse exited");
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
         System.out.println("mouse entered");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think so too, but I can't prove it with the current code posted.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have JDialog with jScrollPane and JLabel inside it. I posted more source code but I'll use GlassPane here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem in better way than using GlassPane. GlassPane only added more troubles to me because I could not scroll JScrollPane which is under GlassPane and redispatching mouse event suggested in glasspane swing tutorial did not help at all because mouseListener on glasspane did not receive mouseDragged.

The solution is by using AWTEventListener. With AWTEventListener I can check for component event is on and event's ID. So my AWTEventListener checks if mouseEntered event occurred over JDialog and if so it is focused programmatically. And if mouseDragged event occurred over JScrollPane I scroll it programmatically. Finally if mouseExited event occurred on JDialog it is hidden.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) event;
                Component mouseComponent = me.getComponent();
                if (mouseComponent == scrollPane) {
                    if (me.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                         scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(me.getPoint());  // scroll JScrollPane programmatically
                    }
                } else if (mouseComponent == ConnectionTreeTooltip.this) {
                    if (me.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED)
                        focusTipLabel(); //focus JDialog(ConnectionTreeTooltip)
                    else if (me.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) {
                        hideTooltip(); //hide JDialog(ConnectionTreeTooltip)
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

But this AWTEventListener works for mouseevents generated from any component in my main frame. And it does not always handle mouseExited event on JDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Or a simpler alternative. Check the coordinates of the mouse on the mouseExited and only count as an exit if the mouse is really outside the control:

```
super.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        Point cursor = e.getPoint();
        if ( (cursor.x < super.getX()) || (cursor.y < super.getY()) || (cursor.x > popup.getX()+super.getWidth()) || (cursor.y > super.getY()+super.getHeight()))
            popup.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```